# Why isn't a Content-Type header allowed in a MultiPart body part?

Tags: okhttp

I'm trying to hack my way around this (I have no control over the server and must add it), but I am very curious to know the reason if anyone knows.
Thanks. (It's on [line 233](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/47964b93fc48a41e25a09276bcd54b7292d3c851/okhttp/src/main/java/okhttp3/MultipartBody.java)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of providing the content type as a header, you need to provide it when building the `RequestBody` instance.

Comment: I have done exactly that and thought it got ignored for some reason! After adding an interceptor to confirm the request got properly formed I saw it having only the Content-Disposition header in the namesAndValues array. But after adding the stetho network interceptor I indeed saw the content-type got added in the request, and my issue was elsewhere. I suppose the default headers live elsewhere, I'll try to figure out where stetho gets them. Thanks for the reply (and the library).